# Need help using Jinja Templates with Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is there a way to add no commands in templates based on difference and not hardcoding any variable to be removed in a separate file? For example:

Ansible task for difference after comparing the running-config with a config in a file:

```yaml
- name: Capture the Existing Config
  set_fact:
    existing_config: "{{ post_output['stdout'][0] | regex_findall('interface \\S+|ip dhcp relay address \\S+') }}"

- name: View the Existing Config
  debug:
    var: existing_config

- name: Required Config Based on Vars
  set_fact:
    required_config: "{{ lookup('file', './Config/{{ inventory_hostname }}.cfg') | regex_findall('interface \\S+|ip dhcp relay address \\S+') }}"

- name: View Required Config
  debug:
    var: required_config

- name: Compare Existing and Required to Remove Unwanted Config
  set_fact:
    config_to_remove: "{{ existing_config | difference(required_config) }}"

- name: View the Difference Against Existing and Required Configs
  debug:
    var: config_to_remove
```

```
TASK [Capture the Existing Config] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View the Existing Config] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "existing_config": [
        "interface Vlan1",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
        "interface Ethernet1/49",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
        "interface Ethernet1/50",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2"
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
    ]
}

TASK [Desired Config Based on Vars] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View Required Config] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "reuired_config": [
        "interface Vlan1",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "interface Ethernet1/49",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2",
        "interface Ethernet1/50",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2"
    ]
}

TASK [Compare Existing and Required Configs to Remove Unwanted Config] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1]

TASK [View the Difference Against Existing and Required Configs] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nxos-1] => {
    "config_to_remove": [
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98",
        "ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99",
    ]
}
```

j2 file to build config:

```
{% for ip in config %}
interface Vlan1
  ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }} 
interface Ethernet1/49
  ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }} 
interface Ethernet1/50
  ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }} 
{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
vars:
  config:
    10.1.1.2
```

Note: No commands are coming from a list based on the difference

Can I use an if statement to use no command based on items from a list within the playbook?

```
{% if <ip is not in vars> %}
  no ip dhcp relay address <ip to be removed>
{% endif %}
```

So the final config file will look similar to the following which will then be pushed to the devices is separate task:

```
interface Vlan1
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99 
interface Ethernet1/49
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99 
interface Ethernet1/50
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98 
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
```

Comment: What does `config_to_remove` contains? And even what does `existing_config` and `required_config` contains?

Comment: And are your sure this is want you want to achieve: `{% if ip not in config_to_remove %}` would then come around a for that would create the different `no ip dhcp relay address <some-ip-here>` are you sure you don't want a simple loop that will have a `{% if ip != item_you_are_looping_on_from_config_to_remove %}`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I have updated the question with contents and outputs of my files, please have a look. Will appreciate if you could recommend me the best solution in this case scenario

Comment: mhm... I don't know what would be all your case scenarios, but I would say your trial is quite naive, by doing a diff of the two lists, you might end up thinking that something is under `interface Vlan1` while it might well be under `interface Ethernet1/48`, if not present in the other list, aren't you?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Nope, these are the only 3 interfaces under which I will the adding the no config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of task, and since Ansible/Jinja is Python, you can even use the wonderful [`for ... if`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#loop-filtering) construct.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          #jinja2: trim_blocks:False
          {% for ip in config %}
          interface Vlan1
            ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }}
            {%- for to_remove in config_to_remove if ip not in to_remove %}
            no {{ to_remove }}
            {%- endfor %}
          interface Ethernet1/49
            ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }}
            {%- for to_remove in config_to_remove if ip not in to_remove %}
            no {{ to_remove }}
            {%- endfor %} 
          interface Ethernet1/50
            ip dhcp relay address {{ ip }} 
            {%- for to_remove in config_to_remove if ip not in to_remove %}
            no {{ to_remove }}
            {%- endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        guess_on_existing_config:
          - interface Vlan1
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
          - interface Ethernet1/49
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
          - interface Ethernet1/50
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
        guess_on_required_config:
          - interface Vlan1
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
          - interface Ethernet1/49
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
          - interface Ethernet1/50
          - ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
        config:
          - 10.1.1.2
        config_to_remove: "{{ guess_on_existing_config | difference(guess_on_required_config) }}"
```

This yields:

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml -i inventory.yml | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "
interface Vlan1
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
interface Ethernet1/49
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99 
interface Ethernet1/50
  ip dhcp relay address 10.1.1.2
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.98
  no ip dhcp relay address 10.5.5.99
"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```